# Concat column values based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

This code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['a1', 'a2', 'stop', 'a4', 'a4', 'a5', 'stop', 'a3'],
                  columns=['c'])
```

renders:

```
      c
0    a1
1    a2
2  stop
3    a4
4    a4
5    a5
6  stop
7    a3
```

I'm attempting to produce the following dataframe where values in a column are concatenated until 'stop' value is encountered :

```
columns = ['c1' , 'c2']
data = np.array([['a1, a2','stop'] , ['a4, a4, a5','stop']])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df

           c1    c2
0      a1, a2  stop
1  a4, a4, a5  stop
```

Is this a valid approach, filter the rows where column value is 'stop':

```
df[df['c'] == 'stop']
```

then access the previous rows ?

Comment: What happens to the last `a3` value?

Comment: @coldspeed a3 value should be ignored

Comment: shouldn't it be `[['a1, a2','stop'] , ['a4, a4, a5','stop']]`? not clear where the `a3` in 2nd row comes from

Comment: @SeijiArmstrong your correct, thanks, question updated. Accepted answer still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create a boolean mask by testing the equality of `c` to "stop":

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['a1', 'a2', 'stop', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'stop', 'a6'],
                      columns=['c'])
>>> mask = df['c'].eq('stop')
```

You also specified you want to ignore values after the final stop.  Truncate both series with:

```
>>> stop = mask[::-1].idxmax()
>>> mask = mask[:stop]
>>> c = df['c'][:stop].copy()
```

Now groupby:

```
>>> c.groupby(mask.cumsum()).apply(lambda s: s[s!='stop'].tolist())
c
0        [a1, a2]
1    [a4, a4, a5]
```

With a cumulative sum, `True` maps to 1 and `False` maps to 0.  This serves as the grouping.

A footnote - this logic should work regardless of whether the final value in the Series ends in a `stop` or not.

Comment: @blue-sky Prefilter first: `df = df.loc[:df.c.eq('stop')[::-1].idxmax()]`

Comment: You're computing `df.c.eq('stop')` in a couple of places, so be sure to reuse the mask ;)

Comment: Just a little improvement , why not move the filter outside apply , this will speed it up

Comment: @Wen I'm not sure if that's possible here?  Because `s[s!='stop]` gets applied individually to each sub-Series.  But please edit if I am wrong